# How to show related posts in my website

Tags: database-design

What is the best design to implement a related post feature.
I have a web site where users will post questions.The table has POST_ID,POST_TITLE,CATEGORY,DATE_CREATED,POSTED_USER_ID. Now i want to show the related /similar questions in the page when i show each question.How to do this ? What should be the ideal table structure for this, How do i associate each post with its similar posts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use stackoverflow code :)    Or try the [hosted version](http://www.stackexchange.com).

You probably need to determine keywords for all your stored posts and then see if those keywords are used when you new question is being created. You can also let users tag their posts and apply the same idea. Not a simple task.